# angular form value changes bound to my custom component

Tags: angular

I have a form and a custom component. What I wanna achieve is as soon as any of the form value changes, my custom component is able to figure out which value is changed and the value changed, i.e. `i` and `item.name`. My first hunch is to use the `input`'s `onchange` event. Is there any other way?

```
<form>
    <div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
        <input type="text" name="item{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.name" />
    </div>
</form>
<my-component></my-component>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create top level form then wrap your component inside your form

```
<form >
 <input [(ngModel)]="data" name="d" type="text">
 <app-my-component></app-my-component>
</form>
```

Inside your child component use Viewproviders to get the parent form

```
import { Component, OnInit, Host } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }]
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Host() private parentForm: NgForm) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(d => console.log(d))
  }

}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atedm7